# How to connect database and do crud operation in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I installed Zend Framework 2 and created new module and till printing hello message its working fine.
            Now i want to connect my database and do Basic CRUD operations. I am running it on xampp.

I written

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zend;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

in global.php located in config/autoload.

in controller i written

```
return new ViewModel(array(
    'hello' => $this->getHelloTable()->fetchAll(),
));
```

If i run it `Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException` and
        `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Hello\Model\HelloTable` error is coming.

what did i missed?

> Reference 
>   I am refering this [This](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html)
>
> Edited : getHelloTable

```
public function getHelloTable() {
    if (!$this->helloTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->helloTable = $sm->get('Users\Model\HelloTable');
    }
    return $this->helloTable;
}
```

> @newage

```
public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Hello\Model\HelloTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('HelloTableGateway');
                 $table = new HelloTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'HelloTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Hello());
                 return new TableGateway('hello', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }
```

Comment: This exception means that you didn't registered a table in `service manager`. You need read article carefully https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable.

Comment: I have done it too.But same issue persists

Comment: Please show the method `getHelloTable()`.

Comment: @newage : please check edited question

Comment: Where do you register table in a service manager ? Can you show code ?

Comment: @newage in config/autoload/global.php   return array(
     'db' => array(
         'driver'         => 'Pdo',
         'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
         'driver_options' => array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
         ),
     ),
     'service_manager' => array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                     => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
         ),
     ),
 );

Comment: @newage Am i missing something?

Comment: You need create a table factory. Like this https://gist.github.com/newage/5b4739a8f5a0c151ec9581fac2ba23e9. This code from manual https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable

Comment: @newage  Its there in module.php already

Comment: Ok, show this config please. Maybe you wrong with name for service manager.

Comment: You registered table with name 'Hello\Model\HelloTable' and get from service manager with name 'Users\Model\HelloTable'. You call table with wrong name. If you use PHP 5.4+ I recommend to use syntax for get full class name, like this `Hello\Model\HelloTable::class`

Comment: @newage . No that is not working for me

Comment: What is not working ? Do you changed name in a service locator ? You have name `'Hello\Model\HelloTable'` in Module and call name`'Users\Model\HelloTable'` from service manager. Service manager don't know name 'Users\Model\HelloTable' because it have registered 'Hello\Model\HelloTable'

Comment: @newage ya i have changed dt

Comment: Do you have this error again `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Hello\Model\HelloTable` ?

Comment: @newage  Thank u for your time and effort. I just tried this link http://bigemployee.com/zend-framework-2-simple-web-application-crud-using-ajax-tutorial/ and changed the mysql port to default 3306 its working fine for me. tnx again :-)